# Make Particles go INTO an object

Tags: particles, system

i would like to make an "Charging effect", for that i want an particle system to emit particles from outside, where the particles accelerate to the emiter, also i would like to know how i could make an "Particle zone", where i can set up the area where the particles from outside gets spawned to, like i don't want the charge effect come from the down side, how would i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make a object for the particle emitter, this will be the area where the particles are spawned.
2. Create a new particle system - emitter
3. Change physics to Boids
4. Under Boids brain remove all default options and add "Goal"
5. Set target object as the goal
6. play with particle lifetime and movement values to get good results

[image]